# Spring Boot using Yaml instead of properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I use Spring Boot.
I would like to write my configuration using  YAML instead of properties.

Since I use `spring-boot-starter` the SnakeYAML library is already in the classpath, and SpringApplication should use the YAML version automatically.

> The SpringApplication class will automatically support YAML as an
>   alternative to properties whenever you have the SnakeYAML library on
>   your classpath.

The problem is that the application keep using the application.properties file and if I remove it no configuration are loaded at all.

Can someone help me? this is my main file

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(App.class);
        app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

this is my `pom.xml`

```
....
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

the application.yml file is just

```
tasks: 231232
```

and I try reading the property using the injected environment

```
     @Autowired
      private  Environment environment;

....

        log.info(environment.getProperty("tasks"));
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Can you try to create an attribute of type `String` which is annotated with `@Value("${tasks}")` and check its value?

Comment: everything is well documented [boot-features-external-config](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Comment: Could not resolve placeholder 'tasks' in string value "${tasks}"

Comment: (@Patrick) I know this is the documentation I'm using.

Answer (score 5):

I solve my problem adding

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
<artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
<version>1.16</version>
```

to my pom.xml file. Notice **1.16**, the spring-boot-starter-parent imports **1.17** .

I open an issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6878

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but adding this dependency with the version 1.32, removes vulnerabilities of spring spring-boot-starter-web.

Answer (score 3):

If the specified version has conflicts, you can use this method to remove the version.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was simply that snakeyaml 1.7 jar was corrupted in my local repository. Probably the class was not loaded at run time.

The fact that I do not recieve any error at build not at run time mislead me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add space after `tasks:` Make sure you add the space after colon ( : ). Also in yml indention plays a vital role

```
tasks: 123
```

[Here a syntax page](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/YAMLSyntax.html)

Comment: where are you placing your application.yml file

Answer (score 1):

An update :

Spring Boot 2 has snakeyaml as a transitive runtime dependency for any of its modules.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was using **gradle**... I add this dependency **without version name** in my `build.gradle` (app level) and worked fine for me:

```
implementation ('org.yaml:snakeyaml')
```

Answer (score 0):

use ConfigurationProperties annotation in main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationProperties
public class App {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(App.class);
        app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -5):

The issue seems to be with your yml file

```
tasks:231232
```

should be

```
tasks: 231232
```